# Use like with PDO on JSON-String

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Actualy I know how to use `LIKE` statement with `PDO`

Now I have a DB-Table called e.g. **foobar**

**foobar** contains a JSON-String like:

```
{"firstname":"foo","email":"aaa@aaa.aa","lastname":"bar"}
```

Now before I call my INSERT on the table I want to check if the Email is already in use.

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE foobar LIKE ?", array('%' . $email . '%'));
```

as you can see, I pass the email into the pdo query.
 Notice `->query` is my custom function that handles some stuff. In this case its not important to know what happens.

The problem I have is:

If the entry like above exists then its not possible anymore to add an email thats like:

```
aa@aaa.aa
^^....only two A's
```

So I thought I can simply change

```
array('%' . $email . '%')
```

to

```
array('%"' . $email . '"%')
```

but this doesnt work. Is there a way I can check the whole string part ?

{"firstname":"foo","email":**"aaa@aaa.aa"**,"lastname":"bar"}

Comment: I would use a [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) or a [JSON column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: @bishop i think regexp will bring up the same problem. Viewing the JSON column type seems quite complicated :)

Comment: Is it too late to rethink this?

Comment: @JonStirling you mean to extract the email, add it to the table and checkt it by its own column ? no its not to late but source that i try to denie :D

Comment: This is a problem of database normalization. You're storing multiple values in a single field.

Comment: I'd really suggest rethinking your database design, and putting the important variables into their own columns.

Comment: Doing it this way, (ignoring the JSON column type) is going to be VERY slow, you won't be able to use indexes and have to scan the entire table.

Comment: this is just a sample and of course I could add... ehh... about 34 columns for relevant data... I thought I could get over this nicely by simply adding a json sting ^^

Comment: normalize the data. storing json in a field is fine,as long as you DON'T need to deal with any individual components of the json. You now do, which means the proper solution is to fix your DB design so that this email field can be stored by itself in a separate field.

Comment: so if i get you all right: i should store the email as an identifyer and handle it with an own column ?

Comment: Yes, that's what we're saying: populate `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` columns in `foobar` instead of/in addition to storing the raw JSON.

Comment: ok, thank you all :) I will do so, but In order to my question I still will test @bishop 's answere. Simply to know if it would work.

Comment: While MySQL 5.7 has rudimentary support for JSON that's better than nothing and is worth evaluating, Postgres has *fantastic*, deep support for JSON that allows you to write queries that can access JSON structures that have been indexed on arbitrary values and keys. It's really powerful when dealing with data like this. One day MySQL might catch up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't break the JSON fields into their own columns, then I would suggest a [JSON column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). It's native to MySQL, super fast for JSON of this size, and no more difficult to use than something like `jq` on the command line.

If that's not an option, I would use a [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

```
mysql> select * from foobar;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| json                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| {"firstname":"foo","email":"aaa@aaa.aa","lastname":"bar"} |
| {"firstname":"FOO","email":"aa@aaa.aa","lastname":"BAR"}  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from foobar where json regexp '"email":"aa@aaa.aa"';
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| json                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| {"firstname":"FOO","email":"aa@aaa.aa","lastname":"BAR"} |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is serviceable, but hardly bullet-proof and, to borrow an excellent turn of phrase, will murder performance on anything but trivial row sets.

Comment: "Isn't bullet-proof" is an understatement here. This will murder your database with non-trivial row counts.

Comment: even if I change my DB-Design, this is the correct answere to my question so to all who looking for some similar, please carefully read comments in my question as well! :)

Comment: @Dwza This will get you over a hump but it's no long-term solution. Eventually you'll have to adapt this to a conventional RDBMS structure, like a key-value association table, or cave in and upgrade to a database that can handle JSON properly. Good luck!

Comment: @tadman thank you for this hint, but as i sayed, ill redesign my tablecontent so this will be no matter anymore :) just accapted the answere as an answer to my question, even if i dont use this structure anymore but may there are people out there who need this solution :)